# Executing python file using google app script

Tags: python, google-apps-script

I have a python program which uses selenium to automate downloading in a website. The url is in the google sheets and have done the part where the python program accesses the sheet and does the automation part. I now want to call the python file to execute from the google sheet itself(like a button or something). I am open to any way even if using cloud services as well(but not preferable).

I tried using google colabs or using google apps script solely. But it could not interact with the UI of the website

Comment: You mean adding the `Execute` button inside the excel sheet itself corresponding each URL ?

Comment: Yes an execute button in the excel sheet itself. But there will be only one url, which will get deleted after the process is done